# How to alter Casetracker's comment form?

Tags: 6, forms, hooks, comments, distributions

I'm trying to alter the comment form of the casetracker module to allow changing the "due date" field via comments. Casetracker already does this for other but not for the "due date" field.

I found the `hook_form_comment_form_alter()` function, which calls `casetracker_case_form_common`, which does the actual form assembly. When I add my custom field inside that function, it shows up in the form. But I don't really want to alter casetrackers code, so I made a custom module which also implements `hook_form_comment_form_alter()` and adds the "due date" field (`field_due_date`) to the form. Unfortunatly this doesn't seem to influence the form at all. Although I can see the field in the `$form` array when I do a `var_dump`, it doesn't show up in the form.

I'm probably missing something, since I'm not very experienced in Drupal development. Yet.

I'm running OpenAtrium with all the latest updates.

Can someone help me out? Or at least point me in the right direction?

Thx

edit: my `hook_form_comment_form_alter()`

```
function duedate_form_comment_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $node = isset($form['nid']['#value']) ? node_load($form['nid']['#value']) : NULL;
  if (casetracker_is_case($node->type)) {
    $form['#node'] = $node;

    $default_due_date = format_date(time(),'custom','d.m.Y');
    $form['casetracker']['field_due_date'] = array(
        '#title' => t('Due date'),
        '#type'=> 'date_popup',
        '#date_format' => 'd.m.Y',
        '#value' => $default_due_date,
    );
  }
  drupal_set_message(var_dump($form['casetracker']), $type = 'status');
}
```

Comment: Could you add your `hook_form_comment_form_alter()` implementation to the question?

Comment: I figured out, that if I use `$form['field_due_date']` or even something like `$form['custom_fields']['field_due_date']` it works fine. I just can't add the field to the 'casetracker' fieldset. This will do for now.